# Framebuffer incomplete for texture with integral format

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to render on different textures attached to a framebuffer.

```cpp
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);  
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

It does not seem to work with integral formats (`GL_*I`, `GL_*UI`) though. If I use one of those, `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`.

Am I missing something or are those formats not supported?

Comment: Your problem is that `glTexImage2D` failed for the reason cited in that post. You can't just pass any old `format` parameter and expect it to work. Not unless you want to use `glTexStorage2D`, which I would advise if its available.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm forced to use OpenGL 4.0 so no `glTexStorage2D`. I guess I should have read the wiki pages from the question linked by you more carefully. There is only a small mention about `_INTEGER` formats though.